# How to rotate Selenium webrowser IP address

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, webdriver

I have a Python script that visits a website every 30 sec, and I would need to have a different IP address each time.

What would be the best/most time effective solution?

- scraping free proxies online? Do you know a python script that gather proxies from many sources?
- use Tor browser to have a different IP each time (I'm using selenium on an aws ec2 instance, you guys know a tutorial on how to use Tor browser on Ubuntu server?)
- other methods?

Comment: Just a heads up, some websites block known Tor exit node IPs. We tried to use Tor for this exact purpose once and found we were blocked by some websites that were using services like CloudFlare. It works for some websites though. Also, if memory serves, we didn't use Tor browser we used a Tor plugin for Chrome on Chromedriver.

Answer (score 37):

To gather and use different proxies a robust solution would be to make proxied requests to the website using the newly active proxies which gets listed within the [Free Proxy List](https://sslproxies.org/) using the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
  options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://sslproxies.org/")
  driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable']//th[contains(., 'IP Address')]"))))
  ips = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable']//tbody//tr[@role='row']/td[position() = 1]")))]
  ports = [my_elem.get_attribute("innerHTML") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@class='table table-striped table-bordered dataTable']//tbody//tr[@role='row']/td[position() = 2]")))]
  driver.quit()
  proxies = []
  for i in range(0, len(ips)):
      proxies.append(ips[i]+':'+ports[i])
  print(proxies)
  for i in range(0, len(proxies)):
      try:
          print("Proxy selected: {}".format(proxies[i]))
          options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
          options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(proxies[i]))
          driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
          driver.get("https://www.whatismyip.com/proxy-check/?iref=home")
          if "Proxy Type" in WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p.card-text"))):
              break
      except Exception:
          driver.quit()
  print("Proxy Invoked")
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['190.7.158.58:39871', '175.139.179.65:54980', '186.225.45.146:45672', '185.41.99.100:41258', '43.230.157.153:52986', '182.23.32.66:30898', '36.37.160.253:31450', '93.170.15.214:56305', '36.67.223.67:43628', '78.26.172.44:52490', '36.83.135.183:3128', '34.74.180.144:3128', '206.189.122.177:3128', '103.194.192.42:55546', '70.102.86.204:8080', '117.254.216.97:23500', '171.100.221.137:8080', '125.166.176.153:8080', '185.146.112.24:8080', '35.237.104.97:3128']

  Proxy selected: 190.7.158.58:39871

  Proxy selected: 175.139.179.65:54980

  Proxy selected: 186.225.45.146:45672

  Proxy selected: 185.41.99.100:41258
  ```

Comment: thank you for your time and your answser. Very useful to me!

I had started looking into an open source code called ProxyBroker.
It has a 'serve' function that tun a local proxy server that distributes
   incoming requests to external proxies.

here is the code
https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/blob/master/examples/proxy_server.py

I think it would be quicker to fetch one different working proxy in the pool each time we open the selenium browser.. but I'm not sure how to do this in a robust way..
(I'm using firefox btw)

Tim

Comment: For everyone trying this code, the site updated the HTML source code, in order for this to work `table table-striped table-bordered dataTable` must be replaced with `table table-striped table-bordered`  
furthermore `tr[@role='row']` doesn't have the attribute `@role` anymore, just use `//tbody//tr/td[position() = N]` where `N` is the row cell you need to exctract

Comment: How do we change it without launching a new instance

Comment: @nonoDa  & undetected Selenium Does this give the same results as using a VPN software when using a webdriver?

Comment: @Skittles proxies are not vpn so the answer i think it's no

Comment: Is it just me, or is none of these free proxies working?

Comment: Sometimes some of them works but they are so slow. Gotta pay for real proxies I think @RalfHundewadt

Answer (score 12):

The site 'https://sslproxies.org/' seems got updated.
Here is an updated code -

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import chromedriver_autoinstaller # pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller

chromedriver_autoinstaller.install() # To update your chromedriver automatically
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# Get free proxies for rotating
def get_free_proxies(driver):
    driver.get('https://sslproxies.org')

    table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
    thead = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'thead').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'th')
    tbody = table.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'tbody').find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

    headers = []
    for th in thead:
        headers.append(th.text.strip())

    proxies = []
    for tr in tbody:
        proxy_data = {}
        tds = tr.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
        for i in range(len(headers)):
            proxy_data[headers[i]] = tds[i].text.strip()
        proxies.append(proxy_data)
    
    return proxies


free_proxies = get_free_proxies(driver)

print(free_proxies)
```

You'll get an output in python dictionary like this -

```
[{'IP Address': '200.85.169.18',
  'Port': '47548',
  'Code': 'NI',
  'Country': 'Nicaragua',
  'Anonymity': 'elite proxy',
  'Google': 'no',
  'Https': 'yes',
  'Last Checked': '8 secs ago'},
 {'IP Address': '191.241.226.230',
  'Port': '53281',
  'Code': 'BR',
  'Country': 'Brazil',
  'Anonymity': 'elite proxy',
  'Google': 'no',
  'Https': 'yes',
  'Last Checked': '8 secs ago'},
.
.
.
}]
```