# How to connect proxy using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I try to connect *http://username:password@ip:port* proxy and `options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)` not working. Can you help me?..

Comment: Does your proxy take form: `PROXY = "12.345.678.910:8080"
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)`

Answer (score 0):

To connect a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409418/how-to-rotate-selenium-webrowser-ip-address/59410739#59410739) through [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY = "ip:port"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe')
```