# Errors in ChromeDriver logs using a proxy through Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, proxy, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to test how to use proxies using selenium in python
Here's the code I am trying

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

PROXY = "164.68.123.119:9300"
opts = Options()
#opts.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:/Webdrivers/chromedriver.exe", options=opts)

print(type(driver))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
myPageTitle=driver.title
print(myPageTitle)
assert "Google" in myPageTitle
time.sleep(10)
print(driver.quit)
driver.quit()
```

When running the code without relying on the proxy, I got error logs like that

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:1056/devtools/browser/3bd3f85f-6d2c-4273-87be-a2e108c07626
<class 'selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver'>
Google
[10116:7976:1029/180608.508:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(230)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[10116:7976:1029/180608.509:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(233)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking Bluetooth availability ended.
[10116:10692:1029/180608.527:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:06:08.528] Bluetooth: bluetooth_adapter_winrt.cc:1073 Getting Default Adapter failed.
[10116:7976:1029/180608.527:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(236)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status started. Please report if there is no report that this ends.
[10116:7976:1029/180608.561:ERROR:chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc(240)] crbug.com/1216328: Checking default browser status ended.
[10116:10692:1029/180608.589:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(114)] Failed to parse configuration descriptor.
[10116:10692:1029/180608.725:ERROR:usb_descriptors.cc(100)] Failed to read all configuration descriptors. Expected 1, got 0.
[10116:10692:1029/180608.725:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)] [18:06:08.726] USB: usb_device_win.cc:93 Failed to read descriptors from \\?\usb#vid_0000&pid_3825#5&50adea6&0&1#{a5dcbf10-6530-11d2-901f-00c04fb951ed}.
<bound method WebDriver.quit of <selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="9dde593ef8cb9492d05b49ea42fc0d9f")>>
```

Any idea how to fix such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To initiate Chrome browser using a *proxy* you can try the following solution:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PROXY = "164.68.123.119:9300"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server={}'.format(PROXY))
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\WebDriver\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe', options=options)
print(type(driver))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
myPageTitle=driver.title
print(myPageTitle)
assert "Google" in myPageTitle
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

PS: *`chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc`*, *`device_event_log_impl.cc`*, *`usb_descriptors.cc`*, etc are the result of a generic bug due to Chrome/ChromeDriver compatibility which you can ignore as of now. For details check [Parametrized tests are flaky due to a timeout in recording expensive metrics on startup](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1216328).

---

### Reference

You can find a relevant discussions in:

- [How to rotate Selenium webrowser IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59409418/how-to-rotate-selenium-webrowser-ip-address/59410739#59410739)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am concerned most with the output logs (that show errors) in the console.

Comment: _chrome_browser_main_extra_parts_metrics.cc_, _device_event_log_impl.c_, _usb_descriptors.cc_, etc are generic bugs of Chrome/ChromeDriver compatibility and you can ignore as of now. Raise a new question if you want detailed answer on any of those.

Comment: In fact, that was my question about these errors in console logs

Comment: Added more details.

Comment: In fact, I put all the details I can. The code is working with no problems but as for the logging in console I got error messages. How can I fix those errors and what is the reason for those errors? And is there a way to hide such logging errors if fixing them is impossible?