# Gmail account blocked during logging in using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just finished a Python Selenium script to automate Gmail accounts creation, using 5SIM API to verify and receive verification code. Everything is working fine and emails are created, but the problem is sometimes when I try to login with the created emails, Google block the account cause they know I'm using a bot, and I searched and found that using the same IP for multiple accounts creation can cause this too, so for each email I'm creating, I'm changing and using a different proxy (but sometimes even the proxy I use is already used before by someone else and my account is again blocked) or maybe the speed of creation ?
Google page:

[image: block account]

If someone already got this error or found a solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

[image: Your account have been disabled]

...implies that your [Google Account has been disabled](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/40695?hl=en) as being the account owner you haven't followed  the Google policies of:

- [Google Terms of Service](https://policies.google.com/terms)
- Other policies and terms of [Google products and services](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/147806).

---

### This usecase

In your usecase using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) presumably your account got disabled due to either of the following reasons:

- *Use of multiple accounts for abuse*: You have used automated bots to create fake accounts.
- *Automatic messages*: Sending messages automatically through robodialing.
- *Impersonation & misrepresentation of identity*: Impersonate a person or organization or misrepresent yourself.

---

### Solution

You need to take some measure so your program doesn't gets detected as a [bot](/questions/tagged/bot) following either of the approaches:

- Change Google Chrome user agent while using Selenium.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [Way to change Google Chrome user agent in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49565254/7429447)

- Use rotating proxies to drive Selenium.

> You can find a relevant detailed discussion in [How to rotate Selenium webrowser IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59410739/7429447)

Comment: After some work, i knew that  it's a proxy problem, but i already triyed before to rotate proxy with selenium and change it for each instance, but changing proxy with Selenium is not working for me :( ( So i am doing it manually for now, untill i find a working solution ) Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try running through script in conjuction with proxy chains in order to achieve your proxy rotation. Configure proxy chains as needed to send out to a random address from a list, or set up a script that will automate the process for calling the application through proxy chains